# casting a two parameter function to a pointer to a single parameter function

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers, void-pointers

I have a function that takes two parameters: "var" is the variable that one wishes to modify and "value" is the value for the desired variable.

```
void fun(int var, int value){
    
    var = value;

}
```

I want to call this function by calling a pointer to void BUT using only one parameter, that is, when I call ptrFun(**any value**) I want fun to be called as fun(*default variable*, **value**)

When I try to declare:

```
void(*ptrFun)(int);
ptr = fun;
```

the compiler throws an error that goes like `a value of type void(*)(int, int) cannot be assigned to an entity of the type void(*)(int)`.

Is this possible to be made?

How can I assign `ptrFun` to `fun` so when `ptrFun` is invoked, `fun` will be called?

Comment: When you assign fun to ptr, you might try casting it to the desired signature but why would you ever what to do that?

Comment: @sizzzzlerz Hi! thanks for answering so quickly.
Can you tell me please how to do what you are referring to.
answering to your question, I have a set of function that takes as parameter a handle to several different microcontroller peripherals in order to initialize and configure them. I want those functions to be accesible from the handle itself as "handle.function(parameter)" instead of using 2 parameters as "handle.function(handle,parameter). inside of the handle I declared pointer to void for each function.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. Pick one language and delete the other tag. This question has different answers for the different languages.

Comment: You can explicitly cast to the new type and back to the original type.  If you invoke the function via the new type, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: *"by calling a pointer to void"* -- it is impossible to "call" a pointer to void. What you go on to describe (in text and code) is calling a pointer to a function. That is, you are trying to call a `void (*)(int)` (pointer to function taking an `int` and returning `void`), not a `void*` (pointer to void).

Comment: @Juan_David *"I have [...]. I want [...]"* -- this information should be in the question. As it stands, you have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), the bane of help desks.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new function that fixes one or more arguments to another function is called [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). The C standard does not provide features for partial application.

GCC supports nested functions that can be used to implement partial application, with limitations. With GCC, this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int add(int x, int y) { return x+y; }


void AddTheHardWay(int x, int y)
{
    int AddFixed(int y) { return add(x, y); }
    printf("%d\n", AddFixed(y));
}


int main(void)
{
    AddTheHardWay(3, 4);
}
```

[prints “7”](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:18,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0A%0Aint+add(int+x,+int+y)+%7B+return+x%2By%3B+%7D%0A%0A%0Avoid+AddTheHardWay(int+x,+int+y)%0A%7B%0A%09int+AddFixed(int+y)+%7B+return+add(x,+y)%3B+%7D%0A%09printf(%22%25d%5Cn%22,+AddFixed(y))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+main(void)%0A%7B%0A%09AddTheHardWay(3,+4)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:cg112,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

However, the lifetime of the nested function is only the execution of its containing function, so it cannot be returned from the containing function to be used elsewhere in the program. It could be used within functions called from the containing function, if passed to them via a pointer.

In Clang, [you can do this](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:18,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:18,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:18,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:18),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0A%0Aint+add(int+x,+int+y)+%7B+return+x%2By%3B+%7D%0A%0A%0Avoid+AddTheHardWay(int+x,+int+y)%0A%7B%0A%09int+(%5EAddFixed)(int+y)+%3D+%5E(int+y)+%7B+return+add(x,+y)%3B+%7D%3B%0A%09printf(%22%25d%5Cn%22,+AddFixed(y))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aint+main(void)%0A%7B%0A%09AddTheHardWay(3,+4)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cclang1400,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall+-fblocks%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+14.0.0+(C,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:cclang1400,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall+-fblocks%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+clang+14.0.0+(C,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) with blocks:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int add(int x, int y) { return x+y; }


void AddTheHardWay(int x, int y)
{
    int (^AddFixed)(int y) = ^(int y) { return add(x, y); };
    printf("%d\n", AddFixed(y));
}


int main(void)
{
    AddTheHardWay(3, 4);
}
```

Generally, there is rarely a need for this, and what you want to do can likely be done by some better method.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I guess I have to look up a lot more on that topic. Would you please suggest me some reading or starting point for what you call better method. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is the scope (visibility) of the nested function that is limited.  It's lifetime is almost certainly the duration of the program.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Per GCC documentation, [“If you try to call the nested function through its address after the containing function exits, all hell breaks loose.”](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) It is apparent if you think about the implementation; the containing function has to build something that binds the value of the applied argument, and a containing function can be called recursively, so it has to use the stack or equivalent.

Comment: Yes; but that is because it may be accessing surrounding context.  You can only use it within the scope where it is defined, but the odds are that the code is not recreated in each entry to the scope — the code is there in text segment waiting to be used in the correct context.  There's a big difference between lifetime and scope.  Think of a static variable defined in an inner block of a function.  It's scope is that inner block but it's lifetime is the entire run time of the program.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The documentation clearly says if you try to call the nested function after the containing function exits, all hell breaks loose. I.e., the nested function is not usable after execution of its containing function ends; its lifetime has ended.

Comment: Ok.  Where is there a breakdown in communication?  I think we are mostly vehemently agreeing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Your first comment says the lifetime of the nested function is “almost certainly the duration of the program.” The GCC documentation indicates the lifetime ends when the containing function exits. Those are contradictory statements. Maybe you are saying the code for the function persists for the entire program, but that is like saying the memory of allocated memory persists even if you free it. In the semantic model, an object is no longer usable once you free it, and a nested function is no longer usable once its containing function exits. Their lifetimes end.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: [GCC builds a prologue for the nested function on the stack.](https://godbolt.org/z/YEz7fcsYs) That surprises me some. On one hand, I figured it had to build some code on the stack. On the other hand, I expect stack not to be executable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243941/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-eric-postpischil).